# op amp design for bandgap

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, bandwidth, gain-bandwidth-product

What values of the main parameters of an op amp are suitable in a bandgap reference design? The purpose is to obtain a smaller temperature drift in the range -40 to 125 C.

The model I am using now is an ideal op amp with the following parameters:

```
gain = 835e3;
freq_unitygain  = 1.0e6;
rin = 1e6;
vin_offset = 0.0;
ibias = 0.0;
iin_max = 100e-6;
slew_rate = 0.5e6;
out = 80;
vsoft = 0.5;
```

The schematics of the design is the one from below.

[image]

And the schematics of the op amp is this:

[image]

Is the gain the most important parameter? Or the bandwidth?

Comment: could you elaborate what you plan on doing, probably with a schematic – I'm not convinced I get the idea and thus your question :(

Comment: *Bandung reference design* can you provide a link to this obscure thing?

Comment: @Andyaka it was a typoo. It is bandgap

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am trying to get a stable voltage of 1.2V from the first design. But I have to tune the parameters for the op amp and I am not sure what parameters are more important for this

Comment: @electricalEN why would you have to tune the parameters of that opamp?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would like to have a smaller temperature drift.

Comment: @electricalEN you didn't even **mention** temperature drift in your question, so how were we supposed to know that? Please **edit** your question to explain your design objectives.

Comment: @Andyaka Dinna be a Bunderlog. [ :-) ]